# Domain Driven Development in C# - example web application

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Are there any recommended examples (with source of course) on DDD in C# / Microsoft stack?

Answer (score 2):

[MVC Store Front](http://blog.wekeroad.com/category/mvc-storefront)

Comment: which is now available in source form on Codeplex: 
http://mvcsamples.codeplex.com/

Comment: sorry, it lost me at public default constructors of aggregate roots.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a S#arp Architecture sample very soon.

http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/
http://groups.google.com/group/sharp-architecture

**EDIT: there is a sample app included in the new S#arp Architecture release.** http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/downloads/list
It's in the src/NothwindSample folder. It's just not detailed out in the wiki yet apparently.